# System Admin not able to view cases created by Community Portal Users

Tags: force.com, case, customer-community, community, case-object

This is silly to ask but I have run out of options to resolve this. 
Somehow, System Admins are not able to view the cases created by Community Portal Users. They can view every other case

In production they are able to see but in Sandbox they are not. The only thing that I did in Sandbox is uninstall an unmanaged package related to communities. Am sure the package is not being used and this is only thing that broke. The package name is 'Community'

Am wondering how a package could impact the record visibility of cases for Sys Admins.

I am able to see the record under Cases tab but when I click on it, it shows insufficient privileges. When I query the record in workbench, it says "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY"

Please help

Comment: You've left out a very important detail: the name of the package you removed from your Sandbox. There may be dependencies the package injects someplace in your code related to permissions that you're not aware of. Without know what the package was, anyone who tries to help you will only be guessing.

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked this. I was working on Partial Copy Sandbox where the Community Users didn't get copied from production. This is why any cases that were created by Community Users in production weren't visible to anybody in the Sandbox.